# DataBinding between multiple controls and a single object

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox

Just getting started with data binding in C# and looking for some help. The below binding statements break (Visible property stops toggling with MyBool & MyBoolInverse) when the line binding SelectedItem of the combo box to MyEnumVar of the BusinessObject executes. Binding directly to the object instead of the BindingSource, or binding to SelectedValue instead of SelectedItem, has the same effect. Further, the value of MyEnumVar doesn't change with selections to the combo box. What am I doing wrong?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    private BusinessObject bo = new BusinessObject();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        bs.DataSource = bo;

        // Checkbox determines what type of dialog to display.
        boolCheckBox.DataBindings.Add("Checked", bs, "MyBool", true,
            DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);

        trueBox.DataBindings.Add("Visible", bs, "MyBoolInverse");
        falseComboBox.DataBindings.Add("Visible", bs, "MyBool");
        falseBox.DataBindings.Add("Visible", bs, "MyBool");
        falseButton.DataBindings.Add("Visible", bs, "MyBool");

        myEnumComboBox.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(
            typeof(BusinessObject.MyEnum));
        // Line below breaks above bindings, same for SelectedValue.
        myEnumComboBox.DataBindings.Add("SelectedItem", bs, "MyEnumVar");
    }
}
class BusinessObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public enum MyEnum { RED, BLU }
    MyEnum _MyEnumVar;
    public MyEnum MyEnumVar
    {
        get { return _MyEnumVar; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _MyEnumVar)
            {
                _MyEnumVar = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("MyEnumVar");
            }
        }
    }

    private bool _MyBool;
    public bool MyBool
    {
        get { return _MyBool; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _MyBool)
            {
                _MyBool = value;
                MyBoolInverse = !value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("MyBool");
            }
        }
    }

    private bool _MyBoolInverse;
    public bool MyBoolInverse
    {
        get { return _MyBoolInverse; }
        private set
        {
            if (value != _MyBoolInverse)
            {
                _MyBoolInverse = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("MyBoolInverse");
            }
        }
    }

    public BusinessObject()
    {
        MyBoolInverse = !MyBool;
        MyEnumVar = MyEnum.BLU;
    }

    // Boilerplate INotifyPropertyChanged implementation & helper.
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't say what is the error?

Comment: Edited, what happens is the Visible property stops toggling on MyBool & MyBoolInverse with the last binding statement enabled.

Comment: So setting up a delegate anon method for the SelectedValueChanged event of ComboBox works as expected, with the Visible property binding still working. The reverse direction, with a delegate for the PropertyChanged event, will break the form when activated. And I believe that's the case because I'm not casting the enum to the proper type to assign to the SelectedItem or SelectedValue.

Comment: Scratch the last sentence above, with the manual binding the form breaks except the ComboBox, it and the bound data update perfectly but the rest of the form is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Visible property has problems with binding. Try manual 'binding'. Something along the lines of

```
trueBox.Visible = bo.MyBoolInverse;
bo.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => { 
  if(e.PropertyName == "MyBoolInverse") 
    trueBox.Visible = bo.MyBoolInverse; 
};
```

**Edit:** Also, binding to `MyEnumVar` is not working beacause it is not declared as a public property.

Comment: The property binding remains just as broken with the delegate. I'm more suspicious that I'm binding the ComboBox item/value incorrectly. Keep in mind the SelectedItem binding of the ComboBox doesn't work at all and if it is commented out the Visible binds work.

Comment: I fixed the accessibility, and now what happens is the form goes unresponsive when the ComboBox is used. Up until that point the Visibility property still doesn't work. The Form no longer updating is a good sign at least. I'm starting to think you can't directly bind a selection to an Enum variable.

Comment: @CANTPRO What happens when you press the Pause button in your IDE after form becomes unresponsive? It could be in some sort of a loop. Also, you can now easily debug why binding to Visible is not working - just set a breakpoint and step through the code.

Comment: When I hit pause the Application.Run(new Form1); line in Main is highlighted. Actually the form remains responsive to mouseovers, but I can't put my cursor in any textboxes, and other controls like checkboxes and radiobuttons are unresponsive to clicks. Not sure what code I should step through, I'm breaking BindingSource with my use of it somehow.